# Cómo dejar corriendo un bot en un hosting gratuito (Heroku) sin arriesgar la clave privada de Binanace

Tags: nodejs, heroku, binance

Programé un bot, en node js, para realizar swing trading en Binance y me es muy complicado dejarlo corriendo 7x24 en mi única computadora. Se puede cortar la energía electrica, o internet, además uso la computadora para otras cosas.
Había pensado dejar corriendo el bot en Heroku (hosting free) pero me doy cuenta que mi clave privada de Binance va a quedar expuesa a los managers de Heruko.
Cualquier idea será bienvenida!

Comment: Mi recomendación es que lo hagas con una Raspberry Pi, que eso gasta poca energía. Es como lo voy a hacer yo.

Comment: AQMR gracias por el consejo, yo estaba usando una vieja notebook con un micro ATOM, tanto la ATOM como la RP resuelven  el problema de la privacidad pero no los cortes de luz. Te cuento que estoy usando una EC2 de AWS, free tier por 12 meses, después veré.

Comment: Puedes resolver los cortes de luz con un SAI (no se si podrán ponerse a una Raspberry Pi, pero claro, te durará X tiempo, yo he llegado a tener cortes de luz de 9 horas, ahí ya seguro que no lo soporta. Pero es una opción)

Comment: Muchas gracias AQMR